# Can't use a particular partition for Ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 as a second OS on a laptop that has Windows 7. In Windows, I have created the below partitions:

- C: -> NTFS - 52GB (Windows installation)
- D: -> NTFS - 94GB
- E: -> NTFS - 82GB User Data
- U: -> NTFS -20GB This is where I want to install Ubuntu on.

In the Ubuntu Install/Setup process (using a 10.10 live flash memory) , the last partition (on U:) is not shown separately, but seems to be grouped together with the other NTFS partition.Therefore, I can't choose the 50GB partition as the Linux installation root.

I tried leaving the partition as unallocated space (unformatted without any file system written on it) but Ubuntu still did not recognize it during installation.

1.How can I format this 50GB partition in Windows (either using Windows Disk Manager or some other disk partitioning tool) so that Ubuntu setup can see this partition as a distinct one and allow me to install Linux on it?

2.Can I format this 50GB partition as ext2/3/4 help? If yes, what tool on Windows can allow me to do that?

3.What other solutions do I have to install Ubuntu, whilst maintaining my Windows 7 partitions?

thank u very much.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have upgraded to a "dynamic disk", which is a Microsoft proprietary system that can not be recognized by other operating systems.  You need to convert the disk back to "basic disk".  You will likely need to delete at least one of those partitions as well.

Comment: why would i have to delete a partition?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a major problem with your partition scheme. You see, Ubuntu requires two partitions to install (one of them is for swap memory). Chances are that your current setup groups all the partitions under one extended partition, or quite simply because you only have "free" partition, Ubuntu cannot place itself there. Essentially you would need to erase the 20GB partition, and don't do anything with it (leave it as just blank completely from within windows).

In other words, if it shows up in windows explorer at all - it's a partition and Ubuntu won't be able to use it.

If you can find a partition manager for windows (a third part one, since the tools in windows suck), you could possibly create an extended partition there yourself.

*Sorry if my answer isn't 100% clear.*

Comment: You don't HAVE to have a swap partition, and the Ubuntu installer can quite happily delete the NTFS partition and use the free space to create both the main and swap partitions.  It will make an extended partition for you if one does not exist already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Ubuntu uses **Ext4** filesystem, while you created **NTFS**, which is used by Windows. Windows can't see Ext filesystems. However Ubuntu can manage NTFS systems without a problem. That doesn't mean NTFS fits for installing. Event if it's possible, NTFS would get fragmented.

Secondly, to install Ubuntu, you need a **SWAP drive**. SWAP drive is used when your computer lacks memory. It's usually recommended to make it twice the size of your RAM memory. For example, if you have 2GB RAM, make it 4GB SWAP. However, in my experience (which isn't much). 3GB RAM was more than enaugh for me, so I make 1GB SWAP - I simply don't need it.

**What should you do?**

1. Insert Ubuntu CD.
2. When installing sellect Advanced
   partitioning. (***However***, You may simply select install alongside with windows - simple and effective solution - this way skip all the other points - installer will do the job)
3. Delete the partition you were
   planning to install Ubuntu to.
4. In its place create **SWAP** (you
   can select it in filesystem dropbox
   when creating)
5. *and* a partition with *mountpoint* " **/** "
6. **Optionaly** you can create a partition for " **/home** " folder
   *mountpoint*
7. **OR** set one of NTFS partitions as home (**NOT RECOMMENDED** - never
   tried and I doubt it would work
   well).