# Installer don't detect any partition on drive

Tags: 11.10, installation, partitioning, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use a particular partition for Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47718/cant-use-a-particular-partition-for-ubuntu-installation)

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 x64 on my system (MSI P67A-C43 B.3) and a Western Digital 1,5TB SATA2 (connected to SATA2 controller), but the installer don't detect any partition on this drive. Really there is an NTFS partition that uses whole disk, and there are 400GB of data on this partition. Even if I have reduced the size of this partition of about 100GB, the installer did not detect any partition and reports that drive is empty. I've also tested 11.10 x32 edition, also LinuxMint 12 have the same problem. Also I've tried to use gparted whithout success.
This drive was partitioned and formatted within Windows 7.
There are other Hard drives, but I've disconnected all except this before booting from USB Flash Disk (made by tool that offer pendrivelinux).
How can i install Ubuntu on this hard drive?

Thanks to all and excuse me for my english.

Comment: Formatted within Windows 7? Is there any chance that this disk has a dynamic partition?

Comment: Does running `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` from the Live CD produce any warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and had to use the alternative .iso image and install that way. Once I did this though I had graphics issues. I would try this though.